# Prism - "OnNavigatedFrom" method not be invoked

Tags: wpf, prism

I am trying to use [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/). 
I use Regions in Region. Main region contains two sub regions.

My problem is when I change my main region then  the method "OnNavigatedFrom" of INavigationAware interface implementation is not invoking.
But When I change only one of sub regions then this method is invoking.

I need that the method always is invoked.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `OnNavigatedFrom` of whom? The main region's view model or one of the sub-regions' ?

Comment: When I navigate from sub region to another subregion then it works, But if parent region changes then it does not work

Comment: What does `it does not work` mean? If you navigate the parent region, is the parent's `OnNavigatedFrom` called or not? Do you expect it to call the subregions' `OnNavigatedFrom`, too?

Comment: It means when It does not hit the OnNavigatedFrom implementation. The problem is clear if you navigate parent region then subregion does not hit.

Comment: That's by design, I suppose. It calls the `INavigationAware` methods on _the region navigated_, everything else is up to you.

Comment: You may be right. I don't have an idea. But, I need to catch navigatefrom event for both situation.

Answer (score 0):

The methods in `INavigationAware` are called when a region is navigated. It will not call those on parent or child regions.

The solution is to make the navigated region do the work. So when the main region is navigated, it should doe whatever cleanup is needed in its child regions.